# Xcode 7 building infinite Core Data and Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode7

I have migrated a project to Swift 2, the conversion was painful but I finished it (actually there is some simple warnings but I will fix it). Now I'm having a problem when building the project, it still building for a long time and nothing happen, neither and error.

If I delete the .xcdatamodeld file the project runs normally but of course I need it so I can't remove.

I left all night and not out of it:
[image: Building]

This is from report navigator:
[image: Build Message]

Any one with the same problem?

**Update 1:** The project is running perfectly on Xcode 7.0 (7A220) the problem is on Version 7.1.1 (7B1005)

Comment: It nothing is working then either update the xcode or delete the coredata and re create it.

Comment: Did you clean the project, the build folder, and delete the derived data before rebuilding?

Comment: @Helium3 Yes, I have cleaned and deleted all derived data a lot of times

Comment: @hebertialmeida - what exactly is the issue? It hangs on compiling the xcdatamodeld? Any errors or warnings?

Comment: @Helium3 This is the problem, Xcode is not showing any error on this, and still building infinitely.

Comment: @hebertialmeida - which version of xcode are you running? And which did you do the conversion with?

Comment: @Helium3 Version 7.1.1 (7B1005), I have converted using this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96052/discussion-between-hebertialmeida-and-helium3).

Comment: you probably want to tell us about the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix for me was to remove Xcode restart Mac and install again.